# Autocomplete textfield widget?

Tags: entities, ajax, 7

Does anybody know of a Drupal 7 autocomplete widget for textfields? I've tried Autocomplete Widgets, but the "Autocomplete for allowed values list" widget from that doesn't seem to exist in Drupal 7 -- only the other two widgets show up. My goal is to store plain text but autocomplete from a user profile field. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating autocomplete for a Drupal form textfield is pretty easy.

1. Add the `#autocomplete_path` to the form element
2. Create a menu callback that returns JSON data with `drupal_json`

Answer (score 7):

Try http://timonweb.com/how-create-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-drupal-7

ALSO: 
http://qandeelaslam.com/blogs/cck/converting-texfield-autocomplete-using-drupals-form-api
http://www.elevatedthird.com/blog/enable-ajax-autocomplete-drupal-7-webform-textfield

(Looking for a module,  now.)

Answer (score 3):

There is http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_widgets:

> This module adds 3 autocomplete widgets for CCK fields of type Text
>   and Number.
>
> Autocomplete for allowed values list: This widget can be used for Text
>   and Number fields and it takes candidate values from the defined list
>   of Allowed values of the fields. You can even generate your allowed
>   values list using PHP, so the limit to provide a widget with
>   autocomplete features is your imagination!
>
> Autocomplete for existing field data: This widget can be used for Text
>   only and it takes candidate values from existing values in the
>   database for that field.
>
> (7.x only) Autocomplete for predefined suggestions: This widget can be
>   used for Text only and allows an admin to provide a list of
>   suggestions but still allows users to enter anything they want in a
>   text field. Use this widget to help avoid (but not prevent) variations
>   of the same value. Ex: burger, hamburger, Burger ...
>
> (7.x only) Autocomplete for existing field data and some node titles:
>   This widget works just like the "existing field data" widget above
>   except it will also suggest node titles for nodes of a specific
>   content type(s).